# Segmentation Fault in binning/jack-knife c program

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, coredump, resampling, binning

Why do I get segmentation fault (core dumped)? I can't figure out where the problem is.

The program is supposed to read a data file with thermalised data, bin the data and then resample using a jack-knife method.

No matter how much data is used, I receive a segmentation fault.

```
/* Ben Marshall 12/03/15 
Bin data & Jack-Knife  */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void)
{
  int binSize, i=0, j=0, k=0, s=0, dataSize=0;
  double *data, *binData, *jackData, mean,  test; //variance

  /* open files, therm.dat is the data to be jack-knifed, 
     jack-knife.dat will store the new data  */
  FILE *thermalised = fopen("therm.dat","r");
  FILE *jack = fopen("jack-knife.dat","w");
  if(thermalised==NULL || jack==NULL) {
    return(-1);
  }

  // check amount of data to be used
  while(fscanf(thermalised, "%lf", &test) != EOF) {
    i++;
  }

  // close and reopen file to reset to start of file
  fclose(thermalised);
  FILE *therm = fopen("therm.dat","r");
  if(therm==NULL) {
    return(-1);
  }

  dataSize=i;
  data=malloc(dataSize*sizeof(double));
  binData=malloc(dataSize*sizeof(double));
  jackData=malloc(dataSize*sizeof(double));

  i=0;
  while(fscanf(therm, "%lf", &data[i]) != EOF) {
    i++;
  }

  fclose(therm);

  /* increasing bin size in multiples of 2  */
  for(binSize=1; (dataSize/binSize)>20; (binSize=binSize*2)) {

    /* binning the data */
    for(j=0; j<dataSize; j=(j+binSize)) {
      for(k=0; k<binSize; k++) {
    binData[s] = binData[s] + data[j+k];
      }
      binData[s] = binData[s]/binSize;
      s++;
    }

    /* jack-knifing the binned data */
    for(i=0; i<(dataSize/binSize); i++) {
      for(s=0; s<(dataSize/binSize); s++) {
    jackData[i] = jackData[i] + binData[s] - binData[i];
      }
      jackData[i] = jackData[i]/((dataSize/binSize)-1); 
    }

    /* calculate mean and variance(FINISH!!) of jackData */
    for(i=0; i<(dataSize/binSize); i++) {
      mean = mean + jackData[i];
    }
    mean = mean/(dataSize/binSize);
    fprintf(jack, "%d\t%lf\n",binSize,mean);
  }

  free(data);
  free(binData);
  free(jackData);
  fclose(jack);
  return(0);
}
```

Therm.dat file with 512 data points

```
0.000000
0.000000
-0.680375
-0.680375
-0.680375
-0.350821
-0.887280
-0.995220
-1.252962
-1.252962
-1.252962
-1.687556
-1.901494
-1.387267
-0.661730
-1.270084
-1.071972
-0.331553
-0.331553
0.231933
0.206068
-0.472156
-0.064220
-0.339324
-0.326490
-0.326490
-0.326490
-0.866318
-0.866318
-0.571235
-0.571235
0.289255
-0.609399
0.218489
0.218489
-0.561976
0.309681
0.309681
1.183490
0.242221
0.242221
0.708890
0.708890
0.683819
0.348371
0.285159
0.285159
0.285159
-0.156746
0.274667
-0.005291
0.286612
0.286612
-0.473538
-0.134213
-0.134213
0.165067
0.165067
-0.149541
-0.866894
-0.866894
-0.866894
-0.866894
-0.298544
-0.298544
0.406136
0.123975
0.260068
0.260068
0.645153
1.192939
1.192939
1.359937
0.546329
1.339987
1.349098
0.379595
-0.490413
-0.256790
-0.756331
-0.344652
0.190825
0.021848
0.533022
0.068725
0.068725
0.068725
0.068725
0.068725
0.716304
0.120708
-0.344601
-0.344601
-0.864071
-0.133875
-0.174296
0.685892
0.763051
0.616413
0.105252
1.001374
0.001387
0.001387
0.001387
0.001387
0.856729
0.010591
-0.177193
0.496544
-0.329510
-0.968900
-1.073870
-0.979022
-1.353796
-1.415412
-1.024003
-1.024003
-1.024003
-1.281823
-1.281823
-1.281823
-1.281823
-1.281823
-1.281823
-1.276340
-0.604276
-0.604276
0.241735
-0.057679
0.446233
0.446233
0.812499
1.349643
1.083498
1.083498
1.062126
0.119195
0.559111
0.120574
0.120574
-0.064506
-0.064506
0.262792
0.393765
0.703879
0.037393
0.569609
0.603709
0.603709
0.603709
0.603709
0.211741
-0.136132
-0.411412
0.219343
0.001131
-0.253185
0.090066
-0.390811
-0.390811
-0.697071
-0.761953
-0.282947
-0.282947
0.529573
0.806371
0.619948
0.286835
0.286835
0.710076
0.710076
0.710076
1.047118
1.047118
0.209257
-0.320486
0.437228
0.437228
-0.448875
-1.172709
-1.172709
-0.767286
-0.767286
-0.767286
-0.919685
-0.467507
-0.467507
-0.394832
-0.394832
0.023062
0.023062
-0.432039
-0.638257
-0.638257
0.005328
0.561397
1.318880
1.597995
0.734204
-0.082765
-0.326956
-0.326956
0.003100
0.214446
-0.003320
0.478868
1.333778
1.039363
1.312167
1.649395
1.649395
1.482254
1.482254
0.958699
0.983845
0.217772
-0.033559
-0.068988
-0.184109
-0.843987
-0.332641
0.015332
-0.443388
-0.443388
-1.238509
-1.060085
-0.070902
-0.070902
0.341742
-0.389328
0.512347
-0.460587
-0.876405
-0.824193
-1.554555
-0.753674
-0.519466
-0.122992
-0.437232
0.299364
1.196347
1.280916
0.896763
1.011643
0.832369
0.675100
0.615301
0.425211
0.701377
-0.076070
-0.029239
0.631120
0.579626
0.341775
0.149383
0.149383
1.009203
0.161747
0.822448
0.822448
1.240791
0.484235
0.484235
0.165943
1.093288
0.536774
0.284845
-0.387362
0.170619
0.170619
0.170619
-0.393905
0.205390
0.403015
0.534997
0.763501
0.763501
0.763501
0.999167
0.524351
0.524351
0.419718
-0.419463
-0.419463
-0.815160
-1.106938
-1.172858
-1.172858
-1.209887
-0.934196
-0.934196
-1.289821
-0.355606
0.517273
0.517273
0.116671
-0.018992
0.978757
1.368280
1.057544
0.342433
0.980111
0.645430
-0.112589
-0.419199
-1.189227
-0.503506
-0.510428
-0.510428
0.107349
0.318306
-0.419542
-0.419542
0.114221
-0.738931
-0.738931
-0.738931
-0.738931
-0.927926
-0.927926
-0.577008
-0.577008
-0.577008
-0.577008
-0.102578
-0.311335
0.354756
-0.375415
-0.704244
-0.928206
-0.928206
-0.224889
-0.382932
-0.784753
-0.784753
-0.010049
0.010331
0.010331
0.241014
0.336769
0.510614
0.697081
0.261887
0.114445
-0.511449
-0.404934
-0.359657
-1.349987
-0.498508
-0.780040
-0.225245
0.335179
-0.511846
-0.437551
-0.314674
-0.314674
-0.314674
-0.848702
-0.922187
-0.877289
-0.877289
-0.877289
-0.244820
-0.160898
-0.160898
-0.970461
-0.970461
-0.634152
-0.438910
-0.560479
-0.804812
-0.760734
-0.480944
-0.480944
0.097673
-0.115412
0.665033
0.665033
0.479649
0.126541
-0.066140
-0.066140
-0.193375
0.768804
0.768804
0.565950
0.024579
0.024579
0.678449
0.703008
0.424989
-0.506374
-0.092152
-0.856560
-0.856560
-0.808172
-0.354146
-1.247427
-1.247427
-1.247427
-0.615559
-0.180127
0.485542
0.233292
0.880815
0.880815
0.880815
0.880815
0.583724
-0.246717
0.551569
0.551569
0.558707
0.972352
0.147571
0.015242
0.633824
0.770137
0.263372
0.263372
0.263372
0.263372
-0.136203
0.208565
-0.084859
0.232177
-0.301226
-0.301226
-1.109600
-1.109600
-1.109600
-1.291821
-0.494729
0.190720
0.702423
0.524186
0.524186
-0.366817
-0.366817
-0.304917
0.181145
0.007122
0.669448
0.716738
-0.135397
-0.188442
-0.647237
-0.175581
-0.442751
-0.442751
-0.137842
0.450729
0.648758
0.288951
-0.001317
0.112005
-0.294367
0.276585
-0.241832
0.241945
0.241945
-0.462878
-0.105833
-0.441753
-1.137753
-0.650209
0.203320
0.174555
-0.605070
-0.667136
-0.667136
-0.355055
-0.074939
0.837230
0.837230
0.837230
0.196938
0.182119
0.247177
0.865210
0.018448
0.931659
0.931659
0.709177
0.709177
-0.025761
0.642050
0.127487
-0.427523
-0.584748
-0.584748
0.222443
0.222443
1.019483
1.019483
1.019483
1.465055
0.589628
0.067904
0.067904
-0.622642
-1.007569
-0.876365
-1.184423
-1.385407
-0.547937
-0.303931
0.422156
0.422156
0.257257
0.257257
0.199488
```

Comment: 1st probable reason you don't check if `fopen()` returned `NULL`, 2nd you don't check if `malloc()` returned a valid pointer.

Comment: Please post the smallest input file possible that produces the error

Comment: Style-wise, I recommend learning about `fseek()` on `thermalised` and re-using the same `FILE *` rather than awkwardly declaring another file pointer, closing, re-opening, re-checking for errors

Comment: @BaseZen I have edited and uploaded a small file which results in an error.

Comment: @iharob do I check these two in the same way as I check the file pointers?

Comment: Program runs fine. No blatant newbie errors. Mac OS X 10.3, gcc -Wall -g, jack-knife.dat gets generated instantly for me. You'll need to run under gdb to isolate. One thing I note is you're not checking `fscanf` result properly. It returns EOF on actual EOF, but otherwise returns the # of items successfully scanned, which can be less than the # requested.

Comment: Repeated your input file out to 100,000 lines and ran OK as well. There's something wrong with your environment. Bizarre. Would be very curious as to the ultimate resolution.

Comment: @BaseZen I bet that the file is not in the right place and since the OP is ignoring the return value of `fopen()` the problem is happening, error checking is really important, no matter how difficult/cumbersome it's necessary, otherwise how could you know why this or that?

Comment: Also `fscanf(thermalised, "%lf", &test) != EOF` doesn't ensure that a good read happened, because `0` might be returned meaning that there were no matches.

Comment: @iharob: Huh? He does `if(thermalised==NULL || jack==NULL)`

Comment: Also, `return(-1)` hurts my eyes. `return` is a control-flow keyword; it is not a function! It's amazing how often this is misunderstood.

Comment: @BaseZen I didn't notice that in all the mess/code?

Comment: @iharob sorry, I've only just started to learn c in my computational physics course. What should I do to improve this program? Check the return from 'fopen()' and 'malloc()'? And also is there a way to perform this resampling and calculating the mean without using arrays and allocating memory?

Comment: There is an error: variable `s` gets values greater than `dataSize` (which is 512).  Up to 768. It could be because `s` is not reset to 0 at the beginning of  loop. `malloc` is done for 512 elements. Most probably core dump is here `binData[s] = binData[s] / binSize;`

Comment: If this is computational physics, can you please tell me what is the algorithm supposed to do? because the problem is with the indices inside the `for (binSize = 1 ...` part, check that you even use the wrong index sometimes, or at least that appears so.

Comment: @iharob we are simulating a harmonic oscillator using a metropolis algorithm to generate the data, the data is then checked to see if it is thermalised (if the mean of the first half is within 2 standard deviations of the second half), this is done in other programs. Then this program performs jack-knife resampling on the data with increasing bin size, to eliminate bias we find the smallest bin size where the error starts to plateau

Comment: @AntoJurković Thanks, adding s=0 at the start of the first loop seems to have let the program work up to 10000 data points, however I still get a segmentation fault with larger amounts of data

Comment: `mean` is also used uninitialized.  `gcc -Wall -W -Werror` is your friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code:

```
while(fscanf(thermalised, "%lf", &test) != EOF)
```

This will cause an endless loop if the file contains something that fails to parse as a floating point number.  Use this instead:

```
while(fscanf(thermalised, "%lf", &test) == 1)
```

Why do you then close and reopen the file instead of just calling `rewind()` ?

In the second reading loop, you should be more careful, in case another process is writing the `"them.dat"` file asynchronously.  You should just try to parse as many numbers as you allocated:

```
for (i = 0; i < dataSize; i++) {
    if (fscanf(therm, "%lf", &data[i]) != 1) {
        printf("error: them.dat changed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

You should not return `-1` from `main()`, most systems only support exit status between `0` and `255`.

In the binning phase, you have a potential buffer overflow:

```
for(binSize=1; (dataSize/binSize)>20; (binSize=binSize*2)) {

    /* binning the data */
    for(j=0; j<dataSize; j=(j+binSize)) {
        for(k=0; k<binSize; k++) {
            binData[s] = binData[s] + data[j+k];
        }
        binData[s] = binData[s]/binSize;
        s++;
    }
```

If `dataSize` is not a power of `2`, the last bin may extend beyond the end of the `data` array, invoking undefined behaviour, possibly the crash you are experiencing.  Modify you boundary test to avoid this.

Furthermore, both `binData` and `jackData` are used before initialization.  You should allocate these arrays with `calloc` so they start at `0.0` (on systems with IEEE floats ;-), or intialize them to the appropriate values with a loop.

When you compute the `mean`:

```
    /* calculate mean and variance(FINISH!!) of jackData */
    for(i=0; i<(dataSize/binSize); i++) {
        mean = mean + jackData[i];
    }
```

`mean` is not initialized!

When you print it:

```
fprintf(jack, "%d\t%lf\n",binSize,mean);
```

`"%lf"` is undefined, you should use `"%f"` to print a `double` or a `float`.